# Rasterio Raster merge - horrible result

Tags: python, raster, dem, rasterio

I am merging `.DEM` files from [CUGIR](https://cugir.library.cornell.edu/catalog/cugir-008186?id=23) NY repository, and need to merge files into one larger image for the whole of NY city. I use python 3.6 + rasterio; It works perfectly for all but one file - ["The Narrows"](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cugir-data/00/81/86/zip/cugir-008186-jj46.zip). When plotted separately, this file looks fine, but once merged with any other, creates invalid values (see below). All files have same band and projection...

here is the code snippet:

```
sources = [rasterio.open(path) for path in files]
dest, out_transform = merge(sources, bounds=None, res=None, nodata=nodata, precision=7)

with rasterio.open(files[0]) as src:
    profile = src.profile

profile.update({'dtype':rasterio.uint8, 'count':1, 'compress':'lzw', 'nodata': -32767.0})

with rasterio.open('whole.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(dest.astype(rasterio.uint8))
```

rasterio 1.0.1

[image: before merging]
[image: merged]

Comment: FYI, you can download the 10m resolution NED tiles (and even some higher-resolution of New York) from https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/ . I think (not entirely sure) it's the same dataset hosted on the site you linked. Then you wouldn't have to stitch so many tiny tiles together.

Comment: Post the code you're using

Comment: added the code snippet

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your update.  Did you figure it out?  You're changing the data type to an unsigned 8-bit integer (whole, non-negative numbers ranging 0-255) yet the nodata value is specified at -32767.  The wonky values are probably from integer overflow where the input values are outside of that range.  Note that np.array.astype() doesn't do any scaling, you would have to do that yourself

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be with profile since you don't update transform, width and height parameters but just take them from first file
Try this:

```
profile.update({'dtype':rasterio.uint8, 'count':1, 'compress':'lzw', 'nodata': -32767.0, "transform":out_transform, "width":dest.shape[1], "height":dest.shape[0]})
```